# How do I clear one set of errors on a two form page in zend

Tags: zend-framework, forms, error-handling

I have a one page website that has two seperate forms that need to be posted back to the same page, the problem being, that if I submit one form, the error checking is done on both, so displays error messages for both. What I need is that if form one is submit, only form ones' error messages appear, and not form twos. Is this possible in zend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a problem for zend to do - but it is a problem for you to solve! 
If you give your form a hidden field, or if you have a field ID unique to one form, you should be able to check which form has been submitted in your controller, then you tell zend which form you want it to check. Something like the following should do the job, it will check for a field with the ID `unique_form_one_field` which obviously should only be on form one, this could be a hidden field for example:

```
// Get the forms:
$form1 = $this->_helper->formLoader('form_one');
$form2 = $this->_helper->formLoader('form_two');

// Check if there is a POST:
if (!$request->isPost()) 
{
    // It isn't show the forms:
    $this->view->form_one = $form1;
    $this->view->form_two = $form2;
}
else
{
    // It is, get the POST data:
    $post_data = $request->getPost();

    // Check if form one has been submitted:
    if (isset($post_data['unique_form_one_field']))
    {
        // Check if form one is valid:
        if (!$form1->isValid($post_data)) 
        {
            // Its got an error, display the forms again, form one will now be populated with the data and also the error messages:
            $this->view->form_one = $form1;
            $this->view->form_two = $form2;
        }
        else
        {
            // Form one was valid - do what you want to process it:
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Check if form two is valid:
        if (!$form2->isValid($post_data)) 
        {
            // Its got an error, display the forms again, form two will now be populated with the data and also the error messages:
            $this->view->form_one = $form1;
            $this->view->form_two = $form2;
        }
        else
        {
            // Form two was valid - do what you want to process it:
        }
    }
}
```